# How do i get data of function into controller?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I would like to get the data.projectid and set it into an variable in the controller.
With rapportage/rapport_detail?idKlant=" it works fine but i would like to get the data.

```
 $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: "rapportage/rapport_detail?idKlant=" + klant, 
                                dataType: 'json',
                                error: function(){ alert("Onvoldoende gegevens beschikbaar om rapportage to genereren."); },
                                success: function(data){ // Plaats data op de juiste plek in de tabel 
                                var projectid=data.projectid,
                                    titel=data.titel,
                                    projecttype =data.projecttype,
                                    projectleider =data.projectleider,
                                    projecttype =data.projecttype,
                                    statusproject =data.statusproject,
                                    startproject =data.startproject,
                                    deadlineproject =data.deadlineproject,
                                    omzetproject =data.omzetproject,
                                    kostenproject =data.kostenproject,
                                    margeproject =data.margeproject,
                                    totaalurenproject =data.totaalurenproject,
                                    totaalminutenproject =data.totaalminutenproject,
                                    urenkostenproject =data.urenkostenproject; });
```

with the idKlant i do it like this in the controller.

```
$idKlant = $this->input->get('idKlant');
```

so i thought that i need to do it almost the same. something like this maybe?

```
$test= $this->input->get('data.projectid');
```

Comment: the $this->input->get is in the controller.

Comment: ok try this without single quotes - $test= $this->input->get(data.projectid);

Comment: When i use the variable in the model its undefined.

Comment: Abviously, it is a local variable right . you didn't use . ok store as global

Comment: I dont get what you mean by that? i just want to get the value from the data.projectid in the controller. from an external jquery file.

Comment: even when i give the $test a value like this $test = 1; it still gives :Message: Undefined variable: test